# Why does my code that can be run directly fail to run after adding %timeit and prompt ValueError?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, timeit

My code can run directly `without` adding `%timeit`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(1, 13), columns=['month'])
df['month']=df['month'].apply('{:02}'.format)
```

But I cannot run after `adding` `%timeit`, and it prompts `ValueError`. Why is this?

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(1, 13), columns=['month'])
%timeit df['month']=df['month'].apply('{:02}'.format)
```

```
ValueError: '=' alignment not allowed in string format specifier
```

After I remove `df['month']=`, it can run.

```
%timeit df['month'].apply('{:02}'.format)
395 µs ± 5.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`%timeit` works by running your program multiple times and assessing how long each iteration takes. In the first example, the DataFrame is updated. Notice you'll also get this error if run the following:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(1, 13), columns=['month'])
# month column is all numbers
df['month'] = df['month'].apply('{:02}'.format)

# month column is now all strings not numbers anymore
df['month'] = df['month'].apply('{:02}'.format)
```

```
ValueError: '=' alignment not allowed in string format specifier
```

---

Even more simply you'll get this error running this code ('01' is the value of the first row in the second run):

```
'{:02}'.format('01')
```

```
ValueError: '=' alignment not allowed in string format specifier
```

---

The reason not assigning back works, naturally, is that the DataFrame is not updated and therefore you always start with a numerical value which *can* be used with that format string.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(1, 13), columns=['month'])
# These do not affect the values in DF
df['month'].apply('{:02}'.format)
df['month'].apply('{:02}'.format)
df['month'].apply('{:02}'.format)
df['month'].apply('{:02}'.format)
# Exactly the same as the constructor
print(df)
```

---

From Python's [Format Specification Mini-Language](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec) we can see that this error is notifying us of the inability to set padding for a string value:

| Option | Meaning |
| --- | --- |
| '=' | Forces the padding to be placed after the sign (if any) but before the digits. This is used for printing fields in the form ‘+000000120’. This alignment option is only valid for numeric types. It becomes the default when ‘0’ immediately precedes the field width. |